# Replacing ISP-supplied modem

Tags: networking, modem, vdsl

Is it possible to replace my ISP-supplied modem with an alternative?

My Canadian ISP (Virgin) supplied a Sagemcom Fast 5250 modem/router. I currently use this as a modem only; the WiFi is disabled and the LAN port connects to a TP-Link Deco M9 Plus mesh network which I use for WiFi.

I'm currently setting up Home Assistant running on a Raspberry Pi 4 on-prem but I'm having trouble getting the public Dynamic DNS (duckdns.org) URL to work inside the Deco network. It works fine from outside (on cellular network).

My assumption is that the Sagemcom router isn't correctly performing NAT Loopback/Hairpin routing.

If I'm going to replace the ISP modem then I'd prefer to buy a modem that:

- has no wireless
- supports multiple protocols (VDSL, VDSL2, ADSL etc)
- relatively easy to configure.

Comment: You would have to ask your ISP. Most ISPs track their equipment, and so if you took it out, and put your own modem in, it might not run.

Comment: "Is it possible to replace my ISP-supplied modem with an alternative?" - It depends.  Most countries of legislation require a customer of an ISP to be able to avoid monthly fees.  You will have to contact your provide to see if you are able to replace their equipment with your own.  You will be unable to just connect this hardware, without their involvement, so it's no sweat of your back to call BEFORE you purchase the hardwar.e

Comment: Maybe you are asking the wrong questions.  Are you behind Carrier Grade NAT? If so, changing the router wont help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no problem replacing the router.
The modem you probably have to keep.
If you were supplied a single modem/router then you should be able to install a second router, and then what happens outside your router in the ISP router should not be your concern.

Now the second question about the dynamic IP. If you are not assigned an ip then there is nothing you can do.
Basically if your assigned IP starts with "10" I think you are out of luck using dynamic DNS.